# raspberrypi smartthings-mqtt-bridge auto start not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, smartthings

I am trying to auto start the smartthings-mqtt-bridge using the following command in the .service file:

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pm2 start /usr/local/bin/smartthings-mqtt-bridge

This doesn't work. However, if I type the exact same thing ('$ /usr/local/bin/pm2 start /usr/local/bin/smartthings-mqtt-bridge') from the command window it works ok.

This is the whole smartthings-mqtt-bridge.service code:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Mosquitto Bridge
After=mosquitto1.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/pm2 start /usr/local/bin/smartthings-mqtt-bridge
Type=forking
User=pi
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thanks for the help.